# How to type a function that add a property with generics in typescript?

Tags: typescript

Consider this function:

```js
export function addAge(obj) {
  Object.defineProperty(obj, 'age', {
    value: null,
  });
  return obj;
}
```

Could I use generics in typescript for know that I will return the object for the parameter with a new property?

Using like so:

```js
interface IPerson {
 name: string;
}

const person: IPerson = { name: 'Juan' };

const result = addAge<IPerson>(person);
// result.age // number | null
// result.name // string
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could indeed make `addAge` [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) in the type `T` of `obj`, and return a value which is the [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) of `T` with `{ age: number | null }` or whatever property type you're adding:

```
function addAge<T>(obj: T) {
  Object.defineProperty(obj, 'age', {
    value: null,
  });
  return obj as T & { age: number | null };
}
```

Note that I have to use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) to tell the compiler that `obj` actually has a new property; the call signature of `Object.defineProperty()` doesn't mutate the type of its input, so the compiler has no idea that `obj` is anything but `T` at the end of the function.

(Aside: the actual code here makes `age` a readonly property at runtime, although the type `{age: number | null}` implies that you should be able to set the property as well as get it.  You could use `{readonly age: number | null}` instead, or you could just use `Object.defineProperty()` so that the property is writable, or any number of other ways of setting the property.  I'll consider any of this stuff out of scope for the question, though.)

---

Anyway we can now test it:

```
const result = addAge(person);
/* const result: IPerson & {
    age: number | null;
} */
console.log(result.name.toUpperCase()); // "JUAN"
console.log((result.age ?? 0).toFixed(2)); // "0.00"
```

Looks good.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAQwCaoIIHMCmAeAFQD4AKOAIwCsAuRAgSkQG8AoRRAeSp2gDpUcwGGBwAFAE5wADjnFQAnmSoAaRAHJkuNatbt2AN2QAbEDlpgQRo8raIAvvQDct8TighxSCpRQBnOogAZMwouOYgALbksogAPogWVvbOdixpLMJQssDIEDiIAJKisr4IzLZgyBFmiL5Q4sJYKWkQCHWIMuKlYLRFJWUAvCGV1bRqAFIgyGBqyS1tUIiuvpaLQ2iYuCSd3U4sAPQAVIitYO3Lq73FXWXBunqaNRZRMfGJRimIh-ssp6VGOF4RjgWBIFyMUF4I0BUDgAFUpJ0AMLIXw4Ej0JyIfb7RAAInGcIwADk8b82nAAUCQSQwTgVhDeI9EAB+FmIAAM9F4sIAYjAAB44VAkABMmMc2NxeI5vA5HLJLCAA)

Comment: This is what I need. Thank you.